# Remove dots in the end of attributedText xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Heloo.. I am newbie here for ios, swift and xcode...

I have logic in swift file like:

```
class ExpandableHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {

    func customInit(menu: Menu, section: Int, delegate: ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate) {

        //Create Attachment

        let imageAttachment =  NSTextAttachment()

        var textAfterIcon: NSMutableAttributedString

        switch menu {

        case .HOME:

            imageAttachment.image = UIImage(named:"home")

            textAfterIcon = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " Home")

        :

        }

        //Set bound to reposition
        let imageOffsetY:CGFloat = -3.0;
        imageAttachment.bounds = CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: imageOffsetY,
            width: imageAttachment.image!.size.width,
            height: imageAttachment.image!.size.height)
        //Create string with attachmen
        let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: imageAttachment)
        //Initialize mutable string
        let completeText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "")
        //Add image to mutable string
        completeText.append(attachmentString)
        //Add your text to mutable string
        completeText.append(textAfterIcon)
        self.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail

        self.textLabel?.attributedText = completeText


        :
    }

}
```

But I got result like:

[image]

I have added for all `NSLineBreakMode.by*`, but no one it is prefect to show image and the label: `[image] Home`

How can I remove 3 dots in the end for `textLabel?.attributedText`?

It was really confused me...

So, it is my pleasure for anyone can help me...

env:

1. xCode v. 9.3

Comment: hide this `self.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byTruncatingTail` and check\

Comment: It looks like your labels are too narrow. Have you added any width constraints to your labels?

Comment: try textLabel.numberOfLines = 0

Comment: @chirag90 I have tried to add `textLabel.numberOfLines = 0`, but got same issue

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I disabled / commented self.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.bTruncatingTail` still got same issue...

Comment: check once your textLabel.frame.width

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I added like:
`var theWidth = self.textLabel?.frame.width
print("width: ", theWidth)`
and got
`width:  Optional(0.0)`... This is what you want? sorry if I was wrong

Comment: have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29049052/4056108)

Comment: @andlin How can I any width constraints to labels?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42086132/swift-constraint-autosize-label-width check this

Answer (score 1):

I would not consider truncating your labels by "..." as a problem. You should firstly resolve correct sizing of your labels.

Comment: How did you add the labels? Are they added in a Storyboard or Xib file? If so, you should fix the size issue by adding the required constraints to the label using Interface Builder.

Comment: @andlin I add the labels not in `Storyboard`, it is in a `Swift` file..

Comment: Hi Rudi, try this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/160527/auto-layout-tutorial-ios-11-getting-started | www.raywenderlich.com in general is full of good tutorials, so don't hesitate to start learning there ;-)